# How to switch between python 2.7 to python 3 from command line?

Tags: python, windows, command-line, cmd

I'm trying to find the best way to switch between the two python compilers, 2.7 to 3.3.
I ran the python script from the cmd like this:

> `python ex1.py`

Where do I set the "python" environment in the window's environment variable to point to either python 3.3 or 2.7?

I am wondering if there is an easy way to switch between the two versions from the cmd line?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

For Windows 7, I just rename the `python.exe` from the Python 3 folder to `python3.exe` and add the path into the environment variables. Using that, I can execute `python test_script.py` and the script runs with Python 2.7 and when I do `python3 test_script.py`, it runs the script in Python 3.

To add `Python 3` to the environment variables, follow these steps -

1. Right Click on My Computer and go to `Properties`.
2. Go to `Advanced System Settings`.
3. Click on `Environment Variables` and edit `PATH` and add the path to your Python 3 installation directory.

For example,

[image]

Comment: it is better to copy python.exe and name the copy python3.exe, this way you avoid errors when you use python 3's IDLE, console and other things that depend on python.exe

Comment: It's better not to use renaming tricks and use the PyLauncher installed with Python.  See my answer.

Comment: life saviour answer

Answer (score 173):

No need for "tricks".  Python 3.3 comes with PyLauncher "py.exe", installs it in the path, and registers it as the ".py" extension handler.  With it, a special comment at the top of a script tells the launcher which version of Python to run:

```
#!python2
print "hello"
```

Or

```
#!python3
print("hello")
```

From the command line:

```
py -3 hello.py
```

Or

```
py -2 hello.py
```

`py hello.py` by itself will choose the latest Python installed, or consult the `PY_PYTHON` environment variable, e.g. `set PY_PYTHON=3.6`.

See [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows)

Comment: Being compatible with Unix shebang, you can also use `#!/usr/bin/env python2` or `#!/usr/bin/python2`. However, `#!/usr/bin/python` will not make PyLauncher use Python 2.

Comment: I dont have a py command when I open cmd even I have python2 and python3 installed

Comment: @M.H. on Windows?  Did you install the Python Launcher in setup? Another check to make is that your PATH doesn’t have a syntax error

Answer (score 4):

In case you have both python 2 and 3 in your path, you can move up the Python27 folder in your path, so it search and executes python 2 first.

Answer (score 2):

They are 3 ways you can achieve this using the py command (py-launcher) in python 3, virtual environment or configuring your default python system path. For illustration purpose, you may see tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynDlb0n27cw&t=38s

Answer (score 1):

**simply add both to the env variables and then you have to move the version you want to the top**

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way than all of the above; You can use the PY_PYTHON environment variable. 
From inside the cmd.exe shell;

For the latest version of Python 2

```
set PY_PYTHON=2
```

For the latest version of Python 3

```
set PY_PYTHON=3
```

If you want it to be permanent, set it in the control panel. Or use setx instead of set in the cmd.exe shell.

Comment: this doesn't work for me... both pythons are in path and this would be elegant / the desired solution. What do I do to make this work exactly?

Comment: @user2305193 This variable is used by PyLauncher.  See my answer.

Comment: and that's called with `py`?

Comment: @user2305193 Its part of pylauncher which is installed with Python 3. If you installed 3.3 or later as a system wide installation it will be on your path. If you didn't you'll need to add it to your path.

Comment: @ehambright sorry, please allow the silly question, but how is pylauncher called, like, what do I type into console after setting the local variable (`PY_PYTHON`)?

Comment: @user2305193 - you type "py" into the console.The name of the launcher is py.exe. If you installed it for all users it will be in %SYSTEMROOT%. If you didn't, I think it will be wherever you installed python 3 to, although im not sure 100%

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Python version 3+?

1. Go to your project path
2. Run `py -[version_number_here]` and hit Enter
   -> This will open the Python's Terminal (sort of)

Happy Coding

Answer (score -5):

You can try to rename the python executable in the python3 folder to python3, that is if it was named python formally... it worked for me

Comment: This does not seem to add anything new to the existing answers.