# setting a variable name similar to java and python in cmd

Tags: python, environment-variables, command-prompt

I currently have  python 2.x and 3.x installed on my windows machine, id like to have both for comparison and also 2.x for pygame.

now i know if i want to run a python script in the command prompt i would use the following:

> python filename.py

i know java also uses the "java" prefix before it if you want to run a java file.

Now in doing this, it automatically sets up python 3.x environment, which i dont mind, but i was wondering is it possible to set up 2.x enviroment by setting a variable called "Python2" and another for python 3.x such as "Python3" so that i could set up the environment without having to use the trick of adding the environment each time in the .py script?

this might be a silly question, but im not overly familar with command prompt's enviroment variables and its keywords, i did try googling it but alot of people just ended up suggesting either env path in the file or manually change the enviromental path each time.

Update
My machine is running windows 8.1

Comment: is this a linux? or what flavor of OS do you use?

Comment: `python2 filename.py`? If you are on linux or mac that will already be the case

Comment: Updated the question there

Comment: You can use the `mklink ` command on windows as far as I know,  `mklink python2.exe c:\python27\python.exe` and `mklink python3.exe c:\python34\python.exe` making sure you do it somewhere that is in your path

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

Follow this tutorial (upto step#4): 
http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Then click on NEW -> add the 2 paths with their call names

- Python2,
- Python3,

While doing this, you may want to add all these to PythonX path :

`C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;`

`C:\other-foolder-on-the-path` (other folders)

Comment: I tried the tutorial and your answer and still won't recognize it :/

Comment: Let me check & get back - i have this same setup at my home.

Answer (score 0):

After snooping about SO, i eventually found my answer, i guess it never came up in my initial searches for some reason

[How to switch between python 2.7 to python 3 from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058389/how-to-switch-between-python-2-7-to-python-3-from-command-line)