# How to setup pip for coexisting Python 2.7/3.4?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I am using Anaconda Python 3.4 on a Windows 7 PC now. Recently I am trying to follow the instruction of the book [High Performance Python](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028963.do) to learn some profiling skills. To this end I need to use `pip install` to install several tools. Unfortunately, not all of them support Python 3, and I have to install Python 2.7 now.

Before installing Python 2.7, I would like to know how I should handle with such 2.7/3.4 coexisting system? How do I setup pip so that I could use `pip install` to install packages for different Python versions separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [conda environment](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#create-an-environment) via:

```
conda create --name py27 python=2.7
```

and use this environment for your work with Python 2.7. Activate it with the command `activate py27`, going back to your root environment is just `activate`.

In the `py27` environment you can install pip and all other packages you need.

Answer (score 2):

`pip` is generally located at the `Python27\Scripts` and/or `Python34\Scripts` folder. If you wish to invoke `pip` directly in the command line, these folders should be in your `PATH` environment variable.

Now I would just rename `pip.exe` in `Python34\Scripts` into any other name, for example `pip_for_3.exe`. That way, when I install packages for Python27, I would just use:

`pip install <package name>`

and packages for Python34:

`pip_for_3 install <package name>`

Coexisting Python installations are not a problem, you just have to know which version is invoked every time. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058389/how-to-switch-between-python-2-7-to-python-3-from-command-line) for the same idea.