# Cannot open Gnome Terminal or install packages using pip without sudo in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, gnome-terminal

I have been trying to install python packages and change the permissions of a folder using chmod. I can't remember which folder as it was just the one which the terminal said I did not have permissions for. I cannot even open it from x-term due to a python error(using python 2 print instead of 3?)

[image: http://i.imgur.com/r3Nv31F.png]

Since doing this I have been unable to open the gnome-terminal using the icon, the cursor becomes a laoding icon for a moment and then dissapears without opening the program.

I am also unable to use pip to install programs without using the program in sudo mode

[image: Non-sudo pip3 execution error]

Furthermore I cannot use the import command in python. Note that I have intalled scipy to my machine

[image: Python import error]

Does anyone know what I have done and how I can revert it?

Comment: try switching back to python 2.7!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058389/how-to-switch-between-python-2-7-to-python-3-from-command-line

Comment: He is using pip3 and python3, don't see how this fixes anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrt to the import failing, pip installs modules into the /site-packages directory of your python directory. So I think the issue is that pip installed it in a different python directory than the directory that the system is using when you type `python3`. I would highly recommend using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) when installing packages - this way you can keep your python executable as well as the dependencies all in one place. However, some packages are required to be installed in the system's python directory. wrt pip requiring you to use sudo, how did you install pip? Usually I do `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Comment: I installed pip as you said using sudo apt-get. The problem is that I cannot access packages which have been installed and used previously. I am unable to execute any Python code I have written which contains an import statement as I receive an ImportError. What I am wondering is how I can fix this so that I can import again.  I appear to have a python 3.5 and python 3.6 folders in my /.local/lib folder. Is this normal?

Comment: You should check the /site-packages directory of your system python. If the packages weren't installed there, the imports will fail.  It might be easier to just start fresh using virtualenv.

Comment: Try ```import sys``` and then ```print('\n'.join(sys.path))``` to see where your site-packages directory is

Comment: The result is `/usr/local/lib/python36.zip`, /usr/local/lib/python3.6, /usr/local/lib/python3.6, /usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload, /home/cdn/.ocal/lib/python3.6/site-packages, /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

Comment: Looks good, now run ```ls -al``` on that site-packages folder to make sure scipy is there. If not, pip3 installed it in the wrong directory.

Comment: You seem be right that there are no packages within the site-packages. The Python 3.5 dist-packages folder in the usr/local/lib/python3.5/ folder contains all of the them while the corresponding python3.6 folder contains none of them. How can I make my python use the dist-packages folder like it used it in the past?

Comment: The system will execute the first python it finds. So it is executing python 3.6 instead of 3.5. You can solve this multiple ways - the easiest way is to just remove python 3.6